# insert into multiple rows PDO

Tags: php, pdo

i am struggling with the code to insert into multiple rows.

but ended up getting warnings

```
$rows = array(1,2,3,4,5,6)

$stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO t_worker_history (uid) VALUES (?)");
foreach($rows as $insert) {
    $stmt->execute($insert);
}
```

> **Warning**:  PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the message says, the first parameter needs to be an array, so just put the `$insert` value into one:

```
$stmt->execute(array($insert));
```

See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php). The reason the parameter needs to be an array is to allow for multiple parameters to be bound to placeholders.

Comment: the warning disappeared, and able to insert. but inserting only one row. i have to insert into three rows.Any help please. thanks in advance

Comment: You should check the return status of the `execute`. Try `$stmt->execute(array($insert)) or die($stmt->errorInfo());`

Comment: According to your code you should get 6 rows inserted. What do you get if you `echo $insert;` in the loop?

Comment: i am getting 1,2,3,4,5,6   as required in loop,

Comment: Well if the query isn't failing and there are no duplicate values you should be getting 6 values in the table...

Comment: this is my complete code, $rows = array(1,2,3,4,5,6)

$stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO t_worker_history (uid) VALUES (?)");
foreach($rows as $insert) {
    $stmt->execute($insert);
}, i tried multiple time but in vain

Comment: You're not getting any data inserted at all? or just the first one?

Comment: as per my requirement its should insert into 6 rows, but now inserting only in one row, the first one (1)

Comment: @Prashanth I just tested this code on my server and it works perfectly (I got 6 rows). I notice you're missing a `;` on your first line? My code was this: `$rows = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO t_worker_history (uid) VALUES (?)");
foreach($rows as $insert) { $stmt->execute(array($insert)); }`